# Is restriction of quotient map a quotient map under the following conditions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

This is the theorem that I am trying to prove.

Theorem 1.3.6, Basic Algebraic Topology:

> Let $q: X \to Y$ be a quotient map and $A \subseteq X$. Then the restriction map $q_A: A \to B=:q[A]$ is a quotient map if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $B$ is the intersection of an open and a closed set in $Y$.
> 2. For $C \subseteq B$, $q_A^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $A$ (resp. open in $A$) iff $q^{-1}[C]$ is closed (resp. open) in $q^{-1}[B]$.

I was able to prove that $q_A$ is surjective and continuous. I am trying to show that

$C$ is open in $B$ if $q_A^{-1}(C)$ is open in $A$ for some $C \subset q(A)=B$

So assuming that $q_A^{-1}(C)$ is open in $A$ for some $C \subset B$, using the condition $(ii)$, I get 
$q^{-1}(C)$ is open in $q^{-1}(B)$.

Also, from condition $(i)$,  $B=U \cap F$ for some $U$ open in $Y$ and $F$ closed in $Y$; This gives

$q^{-1}(B) = q^{-1}(U) \cap q^{-1} (F)$

i.e. $q^{-1} (B)$ is open in $q^{-1}(F)$ since $q^{-1} (U)$ is open in $X$

So, $q^{-1} (C)$ is open in $q^{-1} (F)$.

How do I proceed further ?